# Issue getting url after a firebase image upload in flutter

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter

Below is the code I have written to upload the file, and it works the file does upload properly but the string it returns comes out as "Future" rather than the actual download url from firebase.

```
Future<String> uploadFile(StorageReference ref, File file) async {


final StorageUploadTask task = ref.putFile(file);
final Uri downloadUrl = (await task.future).downloadUrl;
String path = downloadUrl.toString();



return path;
}
```

from the most part this was adapted from a tutorial where he got it to print while still in the function but I am trying to get it into a non async function as a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution, you must include the document upload within the asynchronous function.